# Enable edit mode in 3-way diff using sublimerge

Tags: git, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, mergetool

I'm trying to integrate sublime and git together and sublimerge seems to be a great tool except that I can't find a way to allow manual edits when doing a 3-way diff (e.g. a resolve a merge conflict).

Does anyone know of a way to do this (in any version of sublime/sublimerge)?

p.s. Sublime Text 3 and sublimerge v2.10.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. According to the developers (I emailed them), due to limitations in Sublime’s API, edit mode is not available in three-way diff view.

Answer (score 0):

According to this - http://www.sublimerge.com/docs/configuration.html you can merge files using the **[left]** / **[right]** keyboard arrows to choose which version of the line you want to be used or **[shift]+[left]** / **[shift]+[right]** for the whole file.